# Type is not assignable to type providedIn Property ProvidedIn is missing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am trying to create a service with the help of Angular's tutorial https://angular.io/guide/http

I'm using Angular `7.0.7`.

The service would get json data from some url:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable
export class ProductListService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  productListUrl: string = "https://blahblah.com/products";

  getProductList() {
    return this.http.get(this.productListUrl);
  }
}
```

I am getting a squiggly line under `@Injectable()` with the title of this question. Why is that happening, and how do I resolve it?

I have a component which will be using this service:

```
 import { ProductListService } from '../services/productList.service';
 @Component({
   selector: 'app-productlist',
   templateUrl: './productlist.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./productlist.component.css'],
   providers: [ProductListService]
 })
```

Comment: Which angular version are you using? Add brackets to `@Injectable()`

Comment: I am using 7.0.7

Comment: OMG Thanks a lot. I wrote () in the post above but forgot in the code. Angular should do a better job in pointing the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `@Injectable` is not correct. Add the `providedIn` property which reference your component which will use the service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'app-productlist',
})
export class ProductListService {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}
```

Another solution is to just use the decorator like that: `@Injectable()`, and to declare your service in your `app.module.ts` file, as provider

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductListService {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You have missed to add `parenthesis` for `@Injectable()` decorator

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductListService {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}
```